# What does echo PATH $PATH \$PATH do?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

This is in my homework

> What does echo PATH $PATH \$PATH do?

and I don't know how it this works.

- `echo PATH` prints "PATH"
- `$PATH` creates a "PATH" variable... maybe?
- `\$PATH` means that "$" should be ignored in execution.

So that line simply has two `echo PATH` with no real purpose and prints the `$PATH` location?

Comment: Did you try it? `echo $PATH` doesn't *create* a variable, it prints the current contents of an already-existing variable.

Comment: I think i expressed it wrong, this is not something i made, its on my homework, and it works, its just that i didnt knew how did it work

Comment: You should sit at a computer, open a shell, and experiment with three `echo` commands, starting with `PATH`, then `$PATH` followed by `\$PATH`. It's simple to do and self-education is essential for anyone wanting to work in programming or computers. See “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the default shell on ubuntu has been bash for awhile so I will assume that is what you are using, though the below also applies to all POSIX-compliant shells plus others.

`$PATH` expands the variable `PATH` and `\` escapes the next character stopping the shell from interpreting it as a special character.

If we assume `PATH` contains `/bin:/usr/bin` then if you run:

```
echo PATH $PATH \$PATH
```

The shell will first expand the variables (1) and then execute the result (2).

So (1) gives:

```
echo PATH /bin:/usr/bin $PATH
```

Which when run as step (2) would output:

```
PATH /bin:/usr/bin $PATH
```

to the console.

Comment: Is the assumption of bash needed at all? I can't think of any POSIX-compliant shell where this behavior would differ.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it is true, there are many other shells that will give the same behaviour; definitely all POSIX compliant shells, plus many that are not POSIX compliant.

Answer (score -2):

`$PATH` does not create a `PATH` variable, it expands the variable as said. If you want to create a new one you should use:

```
PATH="Something"
```

Comment: Be careful. Modifying the value of `$PATH` can easily mess up your environment, making it difficult to execute any commands. (The question suggests that the OP may not be aware of that.)

Comment: `PATH="Something"` will completely overwrite the path, which, done naively, will make your shell useless. Doing it naively in your login shell script can cripple your account to the point of being useless to an inexperienced user. While the answer attempts to help, it opens a potentially huge can of worms and should have explained the potential problems.